# Огурцы были в вышей степени не зелёные / незелёные

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Огурцы были в вышей степени не зелёные / незелёные.

Answer (score 2):

**Нет** правильных вариантов.

**Пояснение**

1. Наречное выражение " в высшей степени"  усиливает утверждение, но не отрицание.
2. Слова "незеленые" со значением цвета **нет в словаре** РАН.
3. Это сообщение можно записать **иначе,** например:

*— Огурцы какие-то **супер-не-зеленые**!*

*— Это же баклажаны, my dear.*

**О ПРИСТАВКЕ СУПЕР**

**Вопрос № 304405.**
Здравствуйте. Подскажите, приемлемы ли два дефиса в конструкции "***супер-бизнес-план"***?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Да, верно написание с двумя дефисами.

Приставка «супер» всегда пишется **слитно**. Неважно, идёт ли дальше гласная (суперумный), согласная (суперчеловек) или та же самая буква (суперребёнок или суперраскраска). **Исключение** составляют словосочетания, которые пишутся через дефис **(супер-онлайн-курс)** или имена собственные (супер-Маша).

**Словарь**

***В высшей степени*** — 1) **очень, крайне**. Он чувствовал себя в высшей степени несчастным человеком. Чехов, Степь; 2) **совершенно, совсем.** Наплевать мне, товарищи, в высшей степени на деньги, на славу и на прочую муру! Маяковский, Послание пролетарским поэтам.

Источник (печатная версия): Словарь русского языка: В 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. — 4-е изд., стер. — М.: Рус. яз.; Полиграфресурсы, 1999; (электронная версия): Фундаментальная электронная библиотека

**[Предложения со словосочетанием «в высшей степени»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B2+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)**

Comment: Why would you ever decide to hyphenate *супер-не-зелёные*? There's like no reason you can hyphenate it. It should be either *супернезелёные* or *супер не зелёные*.

Comment: Мне так понравилось, красиво!  Прочитать хотя бы можно.  А словечко это, как его ни пиши, все равно неправильным будет, в словарь РАН его точно не запишут.  И статус приставочки СУПЕР надо бы определить: какой словообразовательной моделью пользуетесь, сэр, используя эту приставку?  И чтобы в словаре Ефремовой эта модель была!  Isn't that right, sir?

Comment: Но *незелёные* пишется слитно.

Comment: В переносном значении, но не в значении цвета, my dear. Или они у вас юные и незрелые, но фиолетовые.  Составьте нам контекст, чтобы мы поняли, please. Artistic context!

Comment: *Незелёная моя племянница, то бишь ещё не выросщая, растратила все свои доллары.* *Она Супернезелёная!*

Comment: Но вы же сами говорили, например, что надо писать *супернеинтересный*.

Comment: Вот вас и слушаю.

Comment: Лео, если племянница незелёная, то уже ж, однако, выросшая. :))

Comment: Лео перетрудился сегодня в школе, ничего не помнит. Это не я предлагала его неографику, совсем не я.  А вот его хвоистые ивы в зимне-осеннем лесу мне понравились. Какое воображение! Я рассчитывала не такой же текст про синие огурцы.